# How to pass multiple objects from jsp to controller in spring web mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data

I have one table in which i have roleId field, which has stores the object of role table. But when i populate to the jsp page in the hidden field and when try to pass in controller it throws type cast expression. Can u help me that how can i pass that object from jsp to controller or how to pass multiple objects from jsp to controller.

Comment: Please show the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you handle forms.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/handling-form-validation-with-spring-3.html

You would need to give example of what you are doing to be specific